# what does `getJsonConfig()` do?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

What is the use of `getJsonConfig()` method?
What does this method do? What is the meaning of the below line in `view.phtml`

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getJsonConfig` of the product block returns the js configuration for product price changing.
It returns different values depending on product type (simple, configurable, bundle) or if it has options or not, and depending on the tax settings.
The json it returns is then picked up buy the `OptionsPrice` js "class" in `varien/js/product.js` and changes the price in the browser depending on your selections.
For example, when you select an option for a configurable product, the price is changed accordingly. The same thing happens when you change a bundle product options.

Answer (score 2):

by     `$this->getJsonConfig()`

`$this` refer to block which you have define in layout

If you see in **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml** file

between `<catalog_product_view />` tag you will find below code

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

So in view.phtml $this refer block

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php
```

you can find   `public function getJsonConfig()` there

this will create a product price json as you see in `function getJsonConfig()` will create json including tire price and all

Answer (score 1):

**$this->getJsonConfig()**
The method is part of

class **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View**

```
/**
     * Get JSON encoded configuration array which can be used for JS dynamic
     * price calculation depending on product options
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {

    }

  */
```

Comment: can you please explain me  What is the use of this method?